# Why can I not ssh into RHEL 8.2 when sshd is running and port 22 shows it's open?

Tags: ssh, rhel, sshd

I installed RHEL 8.2 with a free developer license (bare hardware), it looks like sshd is installed, running by default with port 22 already open, I did not have to do anything to install sshd or open the port.

---

```
[root@<hostname> etc]# systemctl status sshd
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-08-17 13:35:12 MDT; 1h 7min ago
   ...
```

but on Windows 10 Pro (with cygwin ssh client installed),

```
ssh <user>@<ip-address>
```

I get this error

```
ssh: connect to host <ip-address> port 22: Permission denied
```

On the RHEL 8.2 installation, in a bash terminal, I can successfully ssh locally: `ssh <user>@<ip-address>` and it works OK.
Any ideas?

---

This is what I am getting:

**From:** 192.168.0.153

**To:** 192.168.0.106

`$ssh -Tv <user>@<ip-address>`

```
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f 31 Mar 2020
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.106 [192.168.0.106] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.106 port 22: Permission denied
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.106 port 22: Permission denied
```

but on 192.168.0.106, it is showing `sshd` running and port 22 open.

On the machine itself, I can ssh (`$ssh <user>@localhost` works)

---

On the server I want to reach, it shows port 22 as open, ssh service enabled (192.168.0.106)

```
#firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
...
  interfaces: enp37s0
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client http ssh
  ports: 22/tcp
...
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [su].

Answer (score 0):

First, check the output of `ssh -Tv <user>@<ip-address>`

It will tell you:

- if it can actually contact the server
- what local private key it is using

Make sure you have:

- generated a public/private key pair in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh`, using openSSH `ssh-keygen` command (`ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P ""`)
- added the content of `id_rsa.pub` to `~user/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server side.

Comment: So at this point, I am not using SSH keys, I am trying to get simple login/password working.

Comment: This is what I am getting:

From: 192.168.0.153
To:      192.168.0.106

```
$ssh -Tv <user>@<ip-address>

OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.106 [192.168.0.106] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.106 port 22: Permission denied
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.106 port 22: Permission denied
```
but on 192.168.0.106, it is showing sshd running and port 22 open.
On the machine itself, I can ssh (ssh <user>@localhost works)

Comment: When I use ssh keys and add the .pub key file on the server side, I still get:  ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.106 port 22: Permission denied

Comment: @devLinuxNC try and stop sshd service, then launch a `/usr/sbin/sshd -dd`: a debug session. Do a ssh from your Windows 10 and check that sshd reacts (in anyway): if it does not, then a network/firewall issue prevents *any* SSH request to reach the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I had my virtual machine set up for a wired connection. I had to turn on the wired connection in the Red Hat settings. Settings -> Network -> Wired Toggle: ON
Once I turned on the wired connection I was able to make my ssh connections externally.